# Yii2. Access control by roles. How can I add 'OR' condition?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I have a controller with the following access restriction:

```
'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index', 'view'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => [RbacComponent::VIEW_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['create'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => [RbacComponent::CREATE_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['update'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => [RbacComponent::EDIT_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['delete'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => [RbacComponent::DELETE_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

How can I add '**OR**' \Yii::$app->user->identity->isOwner() to all that rules?

I tried to use this variant:

```
            [
                'actions' => ['index', 'view'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => [RbacComponent::VIEW_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
                'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    return \Yii::$app->user->identity->isOwner();
                }
            ],
```

But, in this case, it will be '**AND**' and won't work.

I think this variant will work:

```
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        if ($action == 'index') {
                           if (\Yii::$app->user->identity->isOwner() || \Yii::$app->user->can(RbacComponent::VIEW_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY)) {
                              return true;
                          }
                        }

                        ... other actions

                    }
                ],
```

But maybe there is better and simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a rule with your callback :

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'actions' => ['index', 'view'],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => [RbacComponent::VIEW_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
    ],
    [
        'actions' => ['create'],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => [RbacComponent::CREATE_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
    ],
    [
        'actions' => ['update'],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => [RbacComponent::EDIT_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
    ],
    [
        'actions' => ['delete'],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => [RbacComponent::DELETE_EXPENSES_ACCOUNTS_KEY],
    ],
    [
        'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
        'allow' => true,
        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
            return \Yii::$app->user->identity->isOwner();
        },
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
[
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['owner'],
],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `owner` is not a role. It's a method.

Comment: But you can make `owner` as role and add some rule for this role.